# Javascript var declaration vs equivalent

Tags: javascript

This could be insanely inane... But I am still learning.

Let's take the lesson from Code Academy(since I am literally learning at that low of level) at section 1 lesson 28.

Instructions:
Write your own if / else statement.
The only instruction is that the result of evaluating the statement is a log to the console of "I finished my first course!".

I wrote:

```
var num = 1;

if(num = 2){
console.log("Testing Fail");
}
else{
console.log("I finished my first course!");
}
```

this did not work... but after thinking a moment I gave a shot

```
var num = 1;

if(num == 2){
console.log("Testing Fail");
}
else{
console.log("I finished my first course!");
}
```

This worked. So. I named my variable num and set it equal to 1. I then said if num is equivalent to 2 then the console.log would write "testing fail" -  else it writes "I finished my first course!"...

It doesn't explain why my first try didn't work.
I declared my variable to equal one, but then I said in my if/else statement that if my variable equaled 2 then to do the condition. Why can I not declare a statement twice, or at least in a conditional statement?

I am missing the logic here... probably simple but I am learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=`  is for assignment and `==` is for logical operator (comparison : equal to). So in the first case (`num = 2`) you  assigned your `num` value to the `2` (assignment returned  value, `2`, so evaluated as `true`) and in the second case (`num == 2`) you checked if `num` equals `2` (evaluated as `false`).

***P.S. :*** There is also `===` logical operator that checks if values are exactly equal (equal value and equal type).

Comment: @Andrew Heid : Glad to help you)

Answer (score 2):

just because of the "=", in te second try you used "==" and works.

This "=" is for assign, for example:

```
var num=2;
```

This "==" is to compare for example:

```
if(num==2)
```

So you can't use an assignment instruction to evaluate an equality, hope you get it :D, good luck in your coding

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out the difference: `if (num = 2)` in first case and `if (num == 2)` in the second case. But nobody has pointed out what exactly happened in the first case. In the first case when you did `if (num = 2)`, the expression `num = 2` assigned `2` to the variable `num`. Javascript assignments return the assigned value. As a result of assignment, number `2` was returned. End result of your expression `if (num = 2)` is equivalent to `if (2)` which is equivalent to `if (true)` because javascript considers `0` as false and any non zero value as true. That is why in the first case you saw `Testing Fail` printed to console.

Answer (score 1):

In first case,
`=` is assignment operator

In second, == is is logical operator.

Actually, it is better to use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: Strict equality is "better" only where you care about the type of the value, otherwise it might be "worse".